# Groovy script to find and replace characters in a XML file

Tags: java, xml, groovy, replaceall

I have the below groovy script snippet, I want to replace some characters inside a list of xml files, How could I do this?

```
println "Remove Invisible characters in CustomMetadata"
def customMetadata = ant.fileScanner {
    fileset(dir: '${target.dir}') {
        include(name: 'customMetadata/*.md')
    }
}
// m is the file 
for (m in customMetadata) {
  //Want to get a content of the file and replace if there's any specified characters
  println("Found file $m")

}
```

Comment: You did not specify the core of your question: what do you want to replace ? what are specified characters ? what for ? do you want to keep valid xml ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace characters in the whole file, just read it with

```
def content = new File('[your file name]').text
```

use a `replaceAll()` to replace your character via regular expressions and write the file back with

```
new File('[your file name]').write(content)
```

For replacing unnecessary whitespaces, this should work.

A "cleaner" solution would be to parse the file, replace the characters in the xml content and write it back. This is more complicated and might lead to some problems with XML namespaces. To give it a try, search for `XMLSlurper` or `XMLParser`: http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html